# TurfJS Add Point to MapBox Map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, turfjs

New to Turf JS and have been looking at integration via the MapBox API. Using the default MapBox.Outdoors map and have been following some of the example TurfJS documentation http://turfjs.org/docs/#point but can't seem to get my point plotting on top of the map. Any suggestions greatly appreciated, the error seems to be in my list line of code in relation to the FeatureLayer.setGeoJSON but I can't figure it out. If I leave the last line active the map doesn't load, if I comment it out the map loads but no pin shows up?

```
<BODY>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFya2d1ayIsImEiOiJjaXNsd2VhMG8wMDdrMzNybmticDJhdnZsIn0.KXcvejg6QplSsAlj8aimjA';

var point = turf.point([35.463453, -97.514914], {
"title": "OKC Thunder",
"description": "100 W Reno Ave, Oklahoma City",
"marker-color": "#6BC65F",
"marker-size": "large",
"marker-symbol": "basketball"
});

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.outdoors').setView([35.463453, -97.514914], 19);
.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(point); // If I comment this line out the map loads with no pin. If I leave this line active the map doesn't load at all?
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to add geojson to the map without converting it first. You need to convert the geojson to a format that leaflet can use. Here is an example that should work for you. It will also bind a popup to the point marker that will display the properties for you. The style part can be done either statically (like for all properties except title) so that it would be applied to all points within the feature collection, or dynamically using each features properties (as is done with title).

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.outdoors').setView([35.463453, -97.514914], 19);

var featureCollection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"title": "OKC Thunder"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [35.463453, -97.514914]}}]};

L.geoJson(featureCollection, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(""+feature.properties+"<br />");
    },
    style: function (feature) {
        style = {
            "title": feature.properties.title,
            "description": "100 W Reno Ave, Oklahoma City",
            "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
            "marker-size": "large",
            "marker-symbol": "basketball"
        };
        return style
    }
}).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the set marker function that mapbox makes available to you. So you can skip creating a feature layer and just use the mapbox-marker function. It is documented here:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.0.1/l-marker/

There is also a description of how to create a simple marker here:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/l-mapbox-marker/

For the code you provided you could just skip the creation of a geojson object via turf.point and just use this:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.outdoors').setView([-97.514914, 35.463453, ], 19);
L.marker([-97.514914, 35.463453], {
  icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
    "title": "OKC Thunder",
    "description": "100 W Reno Ave, Oklahoma City",
    "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
    "marker-size": "large",
    "marker-symbol": "basketball"
  })
}).addTo(map);
```

Or if you want to use geojson with turf.point you could also do it that way:

```
var point = turf.point([-97.514914, 35.463453], {
  "title": "OKC Thunder",
  "description": "100 W Reno Ave, Oklahoma City",
  "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
  "marker-size": "large",
  "marker-symbol": "basketball"
});

var coords = point.geometry.coordinates;

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.outdoors').setView([-97.514914, 35.463453, ], 19);
  L.marker(coords, {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon(point.properties)
  }).addTo(map);
```

Also make sure that you need to flip your point coordinates from
[35.463453, -97.514914] to [-97.514914, 35.463453] to match the geojson specification which is "projected coordinates, longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates"

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2